# How to implement text filtering functions for Visual Studio source editor

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

SunOS had a simple means to add text filter functions to the editor:

- Select text
- Mouse click (don't remember which) to select one of the filters I'd written.
- Text was piped to stdin of the filter, processed, and sent back to the editor on stdout.

I've kluged something similar for Visual Studio.

- Ctrl-C to get text to the clipboard
- Exec the filter via Tools | External Tools
- Filter fetches from the clipboard, processes, and stores back to the clipboard
- Ctrl-V updates editor text

Am I missing some simpler, more-standard Vis. Studio method of doing this (eg, without Clrl-C and V)? Spent quite a bit of time searching docs and didn't come up with anything.